# If a CVE database lists my version of OpenSSH as vulnerable, is it possible that it has been patched but retains the version number?

Tags: openssh, vulnerability

I am using OpenSSH version 7.4p1, in CVE database I found that cpe:/a:openbsd:openssh:7.4:p1 is vulnerable to CVE-2017-15906 https://www.cvedetails.com/cve/CVE-2017-15906/.

Does this mean that for sure my version is affected or is it possible that this version has the same number but is already patched? How can I verify this?

Comment: That's possible. What OS are you running?

Comment: I'm running CentOS Linux

Comment: If it's CentOS (or RHEL, which is what CentOS is based on), then it's a near certainty if something gets patched that the version number does not change.  An explanation of why is a bit out of scope here though.

Answer (score 11):

CentOS is just rebuilt RHEL so your system is safe, if you updated to `openssh-7.4p1-16.el7` or similar that is shipped in CentOS 7.

There is CVE database in Red Hat access portal:

https://access.redhat.com/security/cve/cve-2017-15906

With links to the erratas fixing the issues and with listing of packages fixing the specific issue:

https://access.redhat.com/errata/RHSA-2018:0980

Similarly you can get the changelog of your installed package and it should list something related to this CVE number.

*Discaimer: I was fixing that package in this RHEL version.*

Answer (score 7):

Got fixed in 7.4p1-16, way back in November 2017.

```
$ rpm -q openssh-server
openssh-server-7.4p1-16.el7.x86_64
$ rpm -q --changelog openssh-server | grep CVE-2017-15906
- Fix for CVE-2017-15906 (#1517226)
$ rpm -q --changelog openssh-server | head
* Fri Nov 24 2017 Jakub Jelen <jjelen@redhat.com> - 7.4p1-16 + 0.10.3-2
- Fix for CVE-2017-15906 (#1517226)

* Mon Nov 06 2017 Jakub Jelen <jjelen@redhat.com> - 7.4p1-15 + 0.10.3-2
- Do not hang if SSH AuthorizedKeysCommand output is too large (#1496467)
- Do not segfault pam_ssh_agent_auth if keyfile is missing (#1494268)
- Do not segfault in audit code during cleanup (#1488083)
- Add WinSCP 5.10+ compatibility (#1496808)
- Clatch between ClientAlive and rekeying timeouts (#1480510)
- Exclude dsa and ed25519 from default proposed keys in FIPS mode (#1456853)
$
```

Comment: handy tip - `grep -A20` for "twenty lines `A`fter a match" (and its friends, `-B`efore and `-C`ontext)

Answer (score 2):

OpenSSH 7.4p1 [is affected by CVE-2017-15906](https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-97/product_id-585/version_id-228285/Openbsd-Openssh-7.4.html).

... unless the distributor of that OpenSSH package has patched it.

An example of a distributor patching this particular CVE in an affected OpenSSH package may be found [in this changelog entry for 7.5p1 on Ubuntu](http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/o/openssh/openssh_7.5p1-10ubuntu0.1/changelog) (they have not distributed a patched 7.4p1 as far as I could see after only a brief look):

```
openssh (1:7.5p1-10ubuntu0.1) artful-security; urgency=medium
  * SECURITY UPDATE: DoS via zero-length file creation in readonly mode
    - debian/patches/CVE-2017-15906.patch: disallow creation of empty files
      in sftp-server.c.
    - CVE-2017-15906

 -- Marc Deslauriers <marc.deslauriers@ubuntu.com>  Tue, 16 Jan 2018 08:28:47 -0500
```

[Similarly for Fedora (7.4p1)](https://bodhi.fedoraproject.org/updates/FEDORA-2017-78f0991378).

Unfortunately, CentOS does not seem to have an easily accessible database of package updates (that I could find).

Answer (score 1):

According to the  [bugzilla](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1506630) the security bug is fixed on the `7.6` version for the system based on RHEL 7:

> Fixed In Version:  openssh 7.6

The description on RHEL [CVE-2017-15906](https://access.redhat.com/security/cve/cve-2017-15906)

> The process_open function in sftp-server.c in OpenSSH before 7.6 does not properly prevent write operations in readonly mode, which allows attackers to create zero-length files.

Also this information is available on the  [openssh 7.6](https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-7.6)  release note

> Changes since OpenSSH 7.5
>
> Security
>
> - sftp-server(8): in read-only mode, sftp-server was incorrectly
>     permitting creation of zero-length files. Reported by Michal
>     Zalewski.

The bug is fixed on 10 Apr 2018 for the `openssh-7.4p1` : [openssh security, bug fix, and enhancement update](https://www.redhat.com/archives/rhsa-announce/2018-April/msg00016.html)

Comment: probably there is a bad first link? Anyway, there is no openssh 7.6 in RHEL/CentOS

Comment: But this still does not answer the question, if the version 7.4 in centos is vulnerable or not. I will not let you wait any longer. Just see my answer that will reveal that secret for you :)